# Crashlytics upload failure with firebase-crashlytics-gradle

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, firebase-crash-reporting

I recently migrated to using firebase-crashlytics-gradle rather than the deprecated Fabric plugin. However, I seem to have a compile-time clash with Apache HttpClient, because when I enabled upload of the mapping file, I get the following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':nda:uploadCrashlyticsMappingFileTst'.
> org.apache.http.entity.FileEntity.<init>(Ljava/io/File;)V
```

It looks like the FileEntity in my compile classpath is missing a single-argument constructor accepting a File instance and reading the source code states it's been there since v4.2. When I navigate to FileEntity using Android Studio's "go to class" I end up inside org.apache.http.legacy-android-29.

What's going on here; is Firebase Crashlytics SDK somehow incompatible with targetSDK 29 or what can I do to resolve this issue so that the mapping files are uploaded?

Comment: And how about the code which produces the mess? Your reasoning is obviously wrongful, because [`FileEntity`](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/FileEntity.html) has that constructor. Check out the Android part of this [project](https://github.com/syslogic/cloudbuild-android) (mine), which has it configured properly. If you cannot build that, maybe try to invalidate IDE caches; also delete all Gradle caches.

Comment: Yes it has that constructor... but since v4.2 only! What other conclusion could I possibly arrive at given the signature error I am reporting?

Comment: Clear most likely corrupted IDE / Gradle caches... as this error message makes no sense. If there might be anything that might eventually clash, this would need to be a rather outdated Gradle plugin. If you would build the project I've linked, you could at least be sure that the build environment is sane. Since you've provided no code at all, this question is even more unlikely not to be answered.

Answer (score 0):

So as I thought, the problem was with an old third-part plugin on the classpath. I solved it by enabling obfuscation/minification only for release builds and then made sure the third-part plugin only runs for non-release builds.

Was very hard to figure out, given that the dependency graph is for compile and runtime but not for build time.